# Replace '[' 8 characters ']' with blank

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to replace something in a string with regular explressions but it isn't working out.

I'm trying to replace any occurence of **`[`** followed by **8** characters and ending with **`]`**

e.g. 
replace **`[F2283D02]`** with a **blank space**.

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: what is the regex you tried?

Comment: I don't know nay regular expressions, so I tried some things, but it didnt work, what I have now is: Regex.Replace(i.ItemTitle, "'['([^;]*)']'", "");

Comment: Take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ to learn the basics, if you need more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\[[^\]]{8}\]", "");
```

The [ looks for the opening '['

the [^]]{8} looks for 8 consecutive characters that are not ']'

the ] looks for the closing ']'

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking at hex strings
so, your regex would be

```
\[[0-9A-F]{8}\]
^            ^ escapes required as [ and ] are regex-metacharacters
```

Comment: You can use `[^]]` if it doesn't matter what's in the characters as long as it's not `]`

Comment: @Patashu: You mean `[^\]]`?

Comment: The length is known, and also, it seems like he might want to match *valid* hex later, which is why I wrote that out.

Comment: @Cthulhu: Don't know what hexcodes are, it's something that most anime titles contain.

Answer (score 1):

```
 string input = "Replace [fbzdkdf] with empty";
 input = Regex.Replace(input, @"\[\w{8}\]","");
 Console.WriteLine(input);
```

**output : Replace with empty**

Explanation

**[**    : The backward slash escapes the meatcharacter [ in regex .
**\w{8}** : Match any 8 characters.
**]**    : Escape metacharacter ]

- Escaping means Turn off the special meaning of the next character.
  Backward slash does the escaping.

Don't forget to use

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following expression:

```
@"\[([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})\]"
```

See [sandbox](http://www.rubular.com/r/PQQaObx3gz).

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Have you tried dis:

```
(?<=\[).{8}(?=\])
```

Some explains:

`.{8}` - eight characters of any kind

`(?<=\[)` and `(?=\])` - we look for characters surrounded with '[]' but we don't need to find brackets itself, just need to know if those characters are in brackets

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/eGSoTQYuB9)